# JLabel not showing up on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

For some reason even though I have implemented the validate method in my code, and added my JPanel to my JFrame. I am also trying to get my JLabel to have Comic Sans font and for it to be centered in the screen. Why is my JLabel not showing up on my JPane

```
package math_program;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Canvas 
{
    Images obj = new Images();

    public void paintFrame()
    {
        //Instantiation of objects
        Random gen = new Random();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        //Text
        JLabel problem = new JLabel();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Make frame actually closeable
        frame.setTitle("Math Owl: Alpha V:0.1 (coded by John)");
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(panel); //Add JPanel to JFrame
        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE); //To see if text is even appearing

        //Adding Components
        problem.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        problem.setLocation(400,250);
        problem.setText(gen.nextInt(11) + " + " + gen.nextInt(11));
        panel.add(problem);
        panel.validate();

    }

}
```

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` I would recommend using an appropriate [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: I already did panel.setLayout(null); WHY IS MY CODE NOT SHOWING MY JLABEL

Comment: That is my point - you are using a `null` layout. I recommend looking at the link provided in my first comment.

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem? Consider accepting one (green checkmark to the left).

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper Layout Manager just as copeg said. Even the default Layout Manager (Flow Layout) will work. Just remove `panel.setLayout(null);` and your JLabel will show up.

Also when I try your snippet code there also problem on `Images obj = new Images();` I assume you already have the Images class defined in your package somehow.
`

Answer (score 0):

```
//frame.add(panel);
frame.setContentPane(panel);

//panel.setVisible(true); // not necessary code
//panel.setLayout(null); // not necessary code
panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE); //To see if text is even appearing

frame.getContentPane().add(problem);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `null` layout, you have to set both the location and the size of *each* component. You set only the location of the label, so you can fix it with `problem.setSize(x, y);`. With that being said, it's just wrong to take this approach. See what your whole GUI design for this frame looks like and choose an [appropriate `LayoutManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Try this:

```
public class MyCanvas {

    public MyCanvas() {

        Random gen = new Random();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel problem = new JLabel();

        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        problem.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        problem.setText(gen.nextInt(11) + " + " + gen.nextInt(11));
        panel.add(problem); // Default FlowLayout

        frame.add(panel); // Default BorderLayout at position CENTER
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Math Owl: Alpha V:0.1 (coded by John)");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyCanvas();
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

- `frame.setVisible(true)` should be the last call you make.
- `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` and `frame.setResizable(false)` are things you usually want to avoid from the user's perspective.
- `frame.setSize(...)` should be replace with `frame.pack()`.
- `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` should be called between `pack()` and `setVisible(true)`.
- No need for `panel.setVisible(true)`, it does nothing for you.
- No need for `panel.validate()` (should be `revalidate()`), it is only needed when changing the layout during runtime.
- The class `Canvas` already exists, use a different name.

Answer (score -1):

There two way
is you are using any layout manager then you can simply show the component by using setSize(new Dimension(width, height)

if you have set the layout manager to null then you must use
setBounds(x,y, width, height) (if you do this obviously no need to set size)  to show the component

otherwise just do
setSize(new Dimension(width,height)
then setLocation(x,y)
if you want to dynamically calculate the position then you can set the initial locaion as setLocation(0,0)
afterwards when all the components are showing you can use your algorithm to recalculate x and y position and again setLocation(x,y)
for e.g.
label1=setSize(new Dimension(100,20)
label1.setLocation(0,0)
Label2=setSize(new Dimension(100,20)

Label2.setLocation((int)label1.getSize().getWidth()+10,20) and so on

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).